# Ngmodel directive with disable property in Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I want to disable inputs when they are not empty after ngoninit call.I mean i preloading data from webservice.

I just wanna disable inputs which is empty at first.

After that if user input something on empty inputs ngmodel works then disabled becoming true i dont wanna do that.

For ex 
lets suppose User.adi empty

```
[(ngModel)]="User.adi"
```

then checking with `[disabled]="User.adi != null "` becoming true if i enter even 1 word.

I just wanna check this disabled at first after preloading data from ngoninitcall.The inputs shouldn't be disabled after user enter some input on it.Hope you understand it. Thanks in advance

My html :

```
<p-fieldset class="profilFieldSet" [legend]="'profilim' | translate " [toggleable]="true ">
    <div class="p-grid p-dir-col" style="margin: 10px 0px;">
        <div class="p-col">
            <div class="p-grid">
                <div class="p-col">
                    {{'adiniz' | translate}} *:
                </div>
                <div class="p-col">
                    <input pInputText type="text" [placeholder]="'gerekli' | translate" [(ngModel)]="User.adi" [disabled]="User.adi != null " />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="p-col">
            <div class="p-grid">
                <div class="p-col">
                    {{'soyadiniz' | translate}} *:
                </div>
                <div class="p-col">
                    <input pInputText type="text" [placeholder]="'gerekli' | translate" [(ngModel)]="User.soyadi" [disabled]="User.soyadi != null " />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="p-col">
            <div class="p-grid">
                <div class="p-col">
                    {{'yasiniz' | translate}} *:
                </div>
                <div class="p-col">
                    <input pInputText type="text" [placeholder]="'gerekli' | translate" [(ngModel)]="User.yasi" [disabled]="User.yasi != null " />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="p-col">
            <div class="p-grid">
                <div class="p-col">
                    {{'maasiniz' | translate}} *:
                </div>
                <div class="p-col">
                    <input pInputText type="text" [placeholder]="'gerekli' | translate" [(ngModel)]="User.maasi" [disabled]="User.maasi != null " />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="p-col">
            <div class="p-grid">
                <div class="p-col">
                    {{'telefonnumaraniz' | translate}} :
                </div>
                <div class="p-col">
                    <input pInputText type="text" [placeholder]="'gerekli' | translate" [(ngModel)]="User.telefon_no" [disabled]="User.telefon_no != null" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="p-col">
            <div class="p-grid">
                <div class="p-col">
                    {{'evadresiniz' | translate}} :
                </div>
                <div class="p-col">
                    <input pInputText type="text" [placeholder]="'gerekli' | translate" [(ngModel)]="User.ev_adresi" [disabled]="User.ev_adresi != null " />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="p-col">
            <div class="p-grid">
                <div class="p-col">
                    {{'isebaslamatarihiniz' | translate}} *:
                </div>
                <div class="p-col">
                    <input pInputText type="text" [placeholder]="'gerekli' | translate" [(ngModel)]="User.ise_baslama_zamani" [disabled]="User.ise_baslama_zamani != null />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class=" p-col ">
            <div class="p-grid ">
                <div class="p-col ">
                    {{'istenayrilistarihiniz' | translate}} :
                </div>
                <div class="p-col ">
                    <input pInputText type="text " [(ngModel)]="User.isten_ayrilis_zamani " disabled="true " />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-grid-row " style=" position: relative; ">
            <p-button [label]=" 'guncelle' | translate " (click)="updateProfile() "></p-button>
        </div>
    </div>
</p-fieldset>
<p-toast></p-toast>
```

My ts :

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpcagrilariService } from 'src/app/servisler/httpcagrilari.service';
import { MessageService } from 'primeng/api';
import { TranslatePipe } from 'src/app/pipelar/translate.pipe';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-profil',
  templateUrl: './profil.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./profil.component.css'],
  providers: [MessageService, TranslatePipe]
})
export class ProfilComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {

  User: any = {};

  constructor(private httpCagriServis: HttpcagrilariService, private messageServis: MessageService
    , private translatePipe: TranslatePipe) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.httpCagriServis.getProfile().subscribe(
      (response) => {
        this.User = response;
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
  }

  updateProfile() {
    console.log(this.User);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to extend your model with some property that clearly states when you expect the input to be disabled. You could for example create a generic class for all your property values that holds both the value and whether or not to disable input. Something like this;

```
class PreloadedValue<T>   {
    public value: T;
    public shouldBeDisabled: boolean;
}
```

You can then bind like this;

```
[(ngModel)]="User.adi.value" [disabled]="User.adi.shouldBeDisabled"
```

Also providing a strong type for User would be a good idea;

```
class User {
   public adi: PreloadedValue<string>;
}
```

..or simpler if you want to break it up;

```
class User {
   public adi: string;
   public adiShouldBeDisabled: boolean;
}
```

Also, as there is only one `User` in your component, you could just set the property as a field in the component;

```
export class ProfilComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
   public User: any = {};
   public adiShouldBeDisabled: boolean;
```

There are a number of design options here. You will need to choose the one that best suits your needs. The point is that you are probably best of with a property that clearly states what you expect to happen. Another option would be to use a [FormControl](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl) that has properties for keeping track of whether or not the control is pristine, dirty, touched etc.

Hope this helps you, good luck.

Comment: Thank you i got the idea but when am trying to assign data to properties of data i am getting undefined error.For ex i declared data as User:any= {} and  i got the data from web service like  this.User = response; then I'm trying to assign   this.User.adi = new PreloadedValue < this.User.adi > (this.User.adi, true); which causes undefined this.User.adi error. How can i define this propertie like normal ones.

Comment: Updated my answer with some more info. Hope it helps you.